# How to add all the columns from 1st table and have only all of the data from 2nd table being displayed?

Tags: sql, mysql, join, merge

I am creating a dbt view where I need to have 1 single SELECT statement. I have 2 tables, A and B. I want to create a view of a table that will be something like this ( a new table result):

- final table should have the table structure of A, so only has all of the columns of table A
- final table should have all the data from table B only
- so all of the data from table B is present and for the fields where it does not have an entry it would say NULL as shown below

I want to do this without having to use CREATE, INSERT, etc just JOINS (if applicable), etc .

```
Table A

id | name | colour | age | height | gender| object
--------------------------------------------------
1. | apple|  red   | null| null   | null  | fruit
--------------------------------------------------
2. | john |  null  | 21  | 186    | male  | person
--------------------------------------------------
3. | jane |  null  | 19  | 162    | female| person
--------------------------------------------------
4. | jude |  null  | 32  | 154    | female| person
--------------------------------------------------
5. | kiwi |  green | null| null   | null  | fruit

Table B

id | name | colour | object | 
------------------------------
1. | apple|  red   | fruit  | 
-----------------------------
2. | kiwi |  green | fruit  |
-----------------------------
3. | berry|  pink  | fruit  |
    

Query:

    SELECT A.*
    FROM A
    JOIN B ON A.id = B.id
    WHERE A.object = "fruit" --> this doesn't make sense

Trying to have something like this . Final Result:

id | name | colour | age | height | gender| object
--------------------------------------------------
1. | apple|  red   | null| null   | null  | fruit
--------------------------------------------------
2. | kiwi |  green | null| null   | null  | fruit
--------------------------------------------------
3. | berry|  pink  | null| null   | null  | fruit
```

Comment: Do you simply want UNION [ALL] instead of JOIN? Show us some sample table data and also the expected result, i.e. a [mcve], to clarify.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the comment - I have added a sample table I hope this helps. Union wouldn't work unfortunately because I don't have the same number of columns right?

Comment: Like `SELECT id, name, colour, NULL as age, NULL as height, NULL as gender, object FROM b;`?  I'm afraid your question isn't very clear. You can make a result set of a query look however you like, but you can't write a query that says "Dynamically look at the structure of TableA and magically make TableB's data fit into it". You can, as I've done here, create NULL columns to make the output look like Table A though.

Comment: Ahh okay thanks for that. Even if there's an overlap of identical rows and columns in both tables, but rather Table A just have additional columns because it also houses other data points?

Comment: @rxe737 Is the comment from *JNevill* is the answer you were looking for?

Comment: Hi @TimurShtatland, and the answer provides better insight into the final solution. Regarding your answer if WHERE clause was disregarded would the information still show ?